# Scala : Can there be covariance in a constructor for defined type?

Tags: generics, scala, covariance

I have the `class Variable[X <: SeqVal[_]](initialState:Calc[X])`

which I instantiate with `new Variable[SeqVal[Float]](Max())` where `Max` is

`case class Max(seq: Int = 0, value: Float = .0f) extends SeqVal[Float] with Calc[SeqVal[Float]]`, and there are other case classes other than `Max`.

This does not compile even though `Max` does implement a variant of the trait `Calc[SeqVal[_]]`.

```
[error] ../Variable.scala:14: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.quasiquant.calc.Max
[error]  required: com.quasiquant.calc.Calc[com.quasiquant.calc.Price]
[error] Note: com.quasiquant.messages.SeqVal[Float] >: com.quasiquant.calc.Price (and com.quasiquant.calc.Max <: com.quasiquant.calc.Calc[com.quasiquant.messages.SeqVal[Float]]), but trait Calc is invariant in type X.
[error] You may wish to define X as -X instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]   extends Variable[Price](Max(), initChildren)
```

I need help in trying to work out how I can change the bounding of `initialState:Calc[X]` so the `initialState` can be set to anything that implements `Calc[X]` (not just `Max`). I would prefer it if i didn't have to add a second type parameter to all the instantiations of `Variable`

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me (Scala 2.9.1).

Comment: Also note that a more traditional phrasing would be `class Variable[X](initialState: Calc[SeqVal[X]])`. I'm not sure if there's a semantic difference. (both compile).

Comment: could you post the code your compiling, as i've only included the snippets for the purpose of this question. I suspect i've missed something which is causing the compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I tried compiling:

```
trait SeqVal[T]
trait Calc[T]

class Variable[X <: SeqVal[_]](initialState: Calc[X])

case class Max(seq: Int = 0, value: Float = .0f)
    extends SeqVal[Float] with Calc[SeqVal[Float]]

object test {
    new Variable[SeqVal[Float]](Max())
}
```

Compiles without errors.

Comment: so the mistake i made was i forgot to include this `case class Price(seq: Int = 0, value: Float = .0f) extends SeqVal[Float] with Calc[SeqVal[Float]] {
  def recalc(input: SeqVal[Float]) = new Price(input.seq, input.value)
}` which i was using in `new Variable[Price](Max())` but i removed it before posting to cut down on the details. turns out it was the problem - and using `new Variable[SeqVal[Float]](Max())` fixed the problem